# Unable to show database table values using dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm having a bean class employee having attributes id,name along with public getters and setters.

I'm using following bean for db connection and getting values from database table.

**TableBean.java:**

```
  public class TableBean{
    public Connection getVConnection() throws Exception{
      String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:globldb3";
      String username = "scott";
      String password = "tiger";
      Class.forName(driver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      return conn;
      }    
    public List<Employee> getPerInfoAll() {
    int i = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    List<Employee> perInfoAll = new ArrayList(); 
     try {
        conn = getVConnection();
            String query = "select * from employee where e_id>5400";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
               perInfoAll.add(i,newEmployee(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
               i++;
             }
             pstmt.close();
             rs.close();
             conn.close();    
      }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return perInfoAll;
     }
```

**Following is jsf page:**

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{TableBean.perInfoAll}" var="e">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Employee id</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{e.id}">
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Employee name</f:facet>
                     <h:outputText value="#{e.name}">
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Kindly reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931360/a-problem-in-hdatatable-implementation/5931489#5931489)) a problem of getter/setter method naming. If your property is named

```
private List<Employee> perInfoAll
```

the getter method must be

```
public List<Employee> getPerInfoAll() { ... }
```

Notice the upper case "P" in the method name.

Furthermore, you don't need the semicolon after the el expression in your facelet.